# How to solve error on mac: build-manifest.json does not exist in Titanium Studio

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, android-json

Im trying to Package my project to Android (.apk) file, but I get this error: ' build-manifest.json does not exist'. 
I can not find any help regarding that error on the web.
Can somebody tell me what the problem can be, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

- Clean your project (Project > Clean Project) and try again
- Try to update Ti Studio with the latest SDK and apply any updates
- Create a clean project and try to build
- Copy required things from tiapp.xml into your new project to test packaging that up for release

More drastic things to try (maybe something is wrong with your setup):

- Check and triple check through this guide: [Installing Android SDK](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK)
- Re-install nodeJS / Java and Android
- Re-install Studio.

One of those steps, hopefully the earlier one's will fix it. Otherwise you will have a more descriptive error message at some point along this process.